# Regex for negation of three @ followed by number and three @ at end

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a requirement to build a regex which is negation of three at the rate symbol `@` at begining, followed by numbers of varied length between 1 to 12 digits and ending with three `@` symbol. Anything other than that should be selected.

Basically my challenge is that i have a dataframe which has a text corpus and a value in pattern `@@@0-9@@@` I want to remove everything except this pattern. I have been able to develop the regex as `[@][@][@]\d{1,12}[@][@][@]` however i want negation of this pattern as i want to do find and replace. For example

```
my name is x and i work at @@@12354@@@ and i am happy with my job. what is your company name? is it @@@42334@@@? you look happy as well!!
```

should return `@@@12354@@@ @@@42334@@@` it will be great to have a space delimier between individual elements thus fethced. Any help?

I will be using this regex in a python pandas dataframe uisng `str.replace` function.

I have tried [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and have come thusfar

**Edit:**Below is data

```
SNo details
1   account @@@0000082569@@@ / department stores uk & ie credit control operations
2   academic @@@0000060910@@@ , administrative, and @@@0000039198@@@ liaison coordinator
3   account executive, financial @@@0000060910@@@ , enterprise and partner group
4   2015-nasa summer internship- space power system @@@0000129849@@@ and testing
5   account technical @@@0000185187@@@ , technical presales, systems engineer
6   account @@@0000082569@@@ for car, van & 4x4 products in the east of england
7   account @@@0000082569@@@ for mikro segment and owners of the enterprises
8   account @@@0000082569@@@ - affinity digital display, mobile & publishing
9   account @@@0000082569@@@ @@@0000060905@@@ -energy and commodities @@@0000086889@@@ candidate
10  account @@@0000082569@@@ for companies department of external relevance
```

Comment: a much simpler regex would be @{3}\d+@{3}

Comment: You may use `.findall` with `r'@{3}\d+@{3}'` and then join the found matches.

Comment: if i do negation as [^@{3}\d+@{3}], it is acting as negation of not only the pattern but also any other numbers ouside this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I meant in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140375/regex-for-not-three-at-the-rate-number-and-three-at-the-rate#comment75299078_44140375):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['at @@@12354@@@ and i am happy with my job. what is your company name? is it @@@42334@@@? you look happy as well!!', 'at @@@222@@@ and t @@@888888@@@?' ]})
>>> df['col1'].str.findall(r'@{3}\d+@{3}').apply(' '.join)
0    @@@12354@@@ @@@42334@@@
1     @@@222@@@ @@@888888@@@
```

The `@{3}\d+@{3}` will match any 1+ digits enclosed with 3 `@` symbols and `.findall` will extract all matches. `.apply(' '.join)` will join the values with a space.

Comment: I am getting typeerror 'TypeError: can only join an iterable'

Comment: @Enthusiast: Please post the exact input data you have. You see my example contains the data initialization. And it works.

Comment: I have added example data

Comment: But how is it initialized? I mean, please post it in a reproducible way, like `df = pd.DataFrame({....})`

Comment: I didn't understand by what it means to initialize?

Comment: Post the whole relevant reproducible code (the code that can be copied/pasted to run and see what Iis wrong).

Comment: @Enthusiast: The error you mention is not caused by my code, it is somewhere in yours. If you need help with this, please post the whole relevant reproducible code.

Comment: Ok, i realized it after debugging for almost 3 hours. It was a solli NaN value in some of the rows. I replaced that with blank space '' that said, your code is correct. I am accepting this as valid answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `replace` with a complicated regex, you can use `join` with `findall` and use simpler regex as this:

```
>>> str = 'my name is x and i work at @@@12354@@@ and i am happy with my job. what is your company name? is it @@@42334@@@? you look happy as well!!'
>>> ' '.join(re.findall(r'@{3}\d{1,12}@{3}', str))
'@@@12354@@@ @@@42334@@@'
```